# Should I use a vertex shader in this situation?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, opengl-es, shader

I'd like to create a motion blur effect by rendering and additively blending moving objects at multiple points in their trajectory over the course of a frame.

I was thinking that the calculation for determining the draw location could be performed in a vertex shader. It seems to me, though, that I might need to employ the use of a geometry shader if I want to avoid passing in the geometry for each render.

What is my best course of action? I am deciding between:

1. Assembling the vertex data for each sub-frame manually and passing it to the GPU each time (I wouldn't need to have a vertex program if I do this)
2. Send the geometry along with velocity values. I can calculate the intermediate position in a vertex shader, though I'm not certain about how to specify that a certain velocity value is assigned to certain groups of primitives. I will need to send in the same vertices once for each sub-frame render because the vertex shader cannot create new vertices.
3. Use a geometry shader to produce all geometry for all sub-frames. I should be able to get all of the sub-frames without passing any data back and forth during the entire rendering process.

The balance I want to strike here is I want a minimum of redundant data-passing while supporting as much hardware as reasonably possible. It seems like I should be able to use a Vertex Buffer Object to store my geometry data, and just pass a few uniforms to send velocity data to the vertex shader on each render. Does that work? Also a VBO buffer is persistent, so for best performance I should be stepping in and modifying geometry data on an as-needed basis, correct?

Another potential problem I don't know how to deal with is that I want to draw my intermediate positions accurately by interpolating the translation and rotation that rigid objects traverse over a frame, rather than just interpolating the resultant vertex positions alone. The difference here is be that a spinning object will leave a curved streak.

Is there some way I can prevent having to issue a call for each separate dynamic rigid object? Maybe I could use a generic vertex attribute to send in my velocity? It would be somewhat redundant because I could have an object with 100 vertices with the same velocity data, but at least then my shader can get a stream of this data this way.

It seems to me that there might not be too much to gain by performing the vertex transformations on the GPU: I would have to pass in a velocity vector, an angular velocity scalar, and a center of mass vector as vertex attributes. It seems like a big waste of bandwidth. However, I can use that data for a potentially large number of "samples" (sub-frame renders).

I've gotten by for a very long time using the OpenGL Immediate Mode but I want to do things right this time around.

UPDATE: See extended comment discussion for the direction this has taken. I'm now fairly certain that multiple samples will not produce a good result because of the "strobe light effect": At some velocities I'll need to use blur for performance reasons. In that case I need to accumulate blurred sub-frames; rendering sub-frames and then blurring it will still leave artifacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to create a motion blur effect by rendering and additively blending moving objects at multiple points in their trajectory over the course of a frame.

That's certainly one way to do implement motion blur. But these days motion blur is implementy by a vector blur postprocessing filter in the fragment shader. See http://www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-242/vector-blur/ for an explanation how it works. For realtime the process must be reproduced with post processing shaders.

Comment: Interesting link. Thanks. I'm rendering a 2d scene and what I'm trying to do is to use the fast graphics pipeline to my advantage to produce higher fidelity results by rendering the same object many times rather than only once and processing that.

Comment: @StevenLu: Vector blur also works in 2D. And what do you refer to by "fast graphics pipeline"?

Comment: My previous implementation of 2d motion blur used a directional blurring method with a fragment shader, the problem is it will blur and blend non-moving objects that are near the moving object as well, which is undesirable. It looked great otherwise.

Comment: I just meant that it is possible for me to send in a tremendous amount of 2d geometry and modern 3d hardware can handle it like a champ because it is designed to process large 3d meshes. I could incur lots of "overdraw" by blending into the same pixel many times but none of it is wasted because it's actually doing exactly what a real long camera exposure does.

Comment: @StevenLu: This kind motion blur however still only accumulates individial sample points. With bad luck, you'll not see a blur, but a "stroboscope" like image. The cool thing about vector blur is, that it isn't prone to this kind of artifact. Also the performance will be even better, because you draw the whole scene only once, and then 3 full screen quads to do the post processing in the shader. Unfortunately I'm currently in the middle of something else, otherwise I'd do a sample implementation of it.

Comment: I see that this vector blur method does a good job of avoiding the blurring of static objects, which I missed earlier. This is good. I would want to avoid the 1-quad-per-pixel madness though, and I should be able to avoid it in 2d by performing the blur on a render buffer and a fragment shader since I don't need to worry about occlusion. You brought up a good point about "strobe" artifacting: I will be able to avoid it if I render enough samples to fully cover the sweep area but for large translations where I cannot afford to render as many samples as it'd require, I will need a blur. Hmm.

Comment: I can use a blurring fragment shader while I render my sub-frames. If I can ensure the blurs meet up and complement each other I can get sub-frame detail that way.

Comment: But the problem with that is I need a whole new set of geometry to represent the "sweep" in that case.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me spamming the chat log here, it is my topic anyhow. You can check out this link http://stevenlu.net/files/April_24_2009.zip which is a demo I made a while back and in it I render the dynamic objects using a fragment shader blur. I'll try to describe it as succinctly as possible. I first render the scene to texture A. I then render velocity-sweep-geometry to texture B. velocity-sweep-geometry is geometry that has had each vertex duplicated and extruded in the direction of velocity. I per-vertex color these vertices with the velocity.

Comment: In my fragment shader I retrieve a full-screen quad and textures A and B. I sample texture B to retrieve the per-pixel interpolated velocity vector value from the color, and sample from texture A along that direction a fixed number of times, and set the fragment color to the average. This is something of a per-pixel directional box blur. Since I failed to separate my static and dynamic objects, the blur would apply on static objects too. So this time around what I am setting out to do is to 1) separate static geometry so it isnt blurred and 2) sample motion more than once per frame

Comment: @StevenLu: This quad per pixel is just the Blender way of doing it (because when this was implemented the Blender renderer didn't have the concept of shaders, like you find them on GPUs). In the case of implementing it on the GPU instead of virtual quads this would happen on the fragments of a full screen quad in a post-processing fragment shader, i.e. there is no complex geometry introduces. So the steps are really just: 1. Render picture into color buffer, 2. Render speed vectors into speed buffer; bind color and speed buffer as textures and render them through a vector blur filter.

Comment: The part that seems to introduce the most complexity is coming up with the geometry for the speed buffer. I need to basically produce geometry that covers the entire area which the object is to be "moving across". I think you can actually toggle and view this buffer in my demo by pressing the '1' key. (Can't double check that for you now because I'm booted into Linux)

Comment: @StevenLu: Modern OpenGL supports writing to multiple render targets. And the speed buffer is filled with values evaluated from the same geoemtry data, also used for the color buffer. The addition is, that for each object you also pass the transformation matrix for the next movement step, to evaluate a d/dt for each vertex. The resulting speed vector is the difference between vertex positions. You need to apply some perspective divide manually. But it really just boils down to aditional matrix passed.

Comment: (speaking in 1d terms w.l.o.g.) If an object covers n pixels then it is incorrect to only draw n blurred pixels. Over some time it travels across some distance, and fragments must be generated for all the area it covers, which is why I've been needing to produce the "swept" geometry. Do you know of some shortcut around that?

Comment: @StevenLu: That's why vector blur is implemented as a post processing filter: First you render the unblurred geometry in two images. One image contains the color, the other image contains the per pixel motion vectors. Then in the postprocessing step you take those two images and apply vector blurring for N blurring distances and M directions. For each n \in N and m \in M you weight by scalar product with the corresponding pixels in the vector image, and sum them up according to weight. The key word is: It's a post processing filter, happening on an image.

Comment: @StevenLu: The virtual quads used by Blender are used, to implement a scatter access, which is more efficient for CPUs. GPUs however are gatherers, so a fragment shader post processing filter can do this better. I guess I'll have to make an example implementation after all, for demonstration… *sigh*

Comment: You dont need to go to the trouble of doing an implementation though I certainly won't stop you. I assure you I do understand the implementation of post-processing blur in the fragment shader, I implemented it in the demo I linked. But the devil's in the details: I'd like my motion to leave a "streak" in addition to just blurring out the rendered image. In fact the blurring can perform that streaking automatically. But in order to actually produce the streak (which extends outside the actual position of the geometry originally rendered) a new set of geometry must be made.

Answer (score 2):

1. Software render the sub-frames - Consider this the "baseline" case.
2. Vertex shader - You could do this, but don't try to send geometry velocity, just send the vertex velocity:

   Render the frame to a VBO, calling glVertexAttrib to include the current velocity and acceleration of each vertex. Render the VBO repeatedly, specifying the time offset for each sub-frame with a uniform value.

   The vertex shader would then need to apply the offests based on the uniform time value.
3. Geometry shader - If you went with this, you could implement it much like #2, except the "loop and vary" would be implemented in the shader instead - helping to offload more work to the GPU.

You also mention:

- Render everything with a VBO - If you used VBOs/display lists like this you would basically be doing option #1 with more hardware acceleration.
- Interpolation problems - It's probably not worth your effort to get an exact interpolation. Unless the objects are moving very fast *and* curving, linear interpolation of speed (first order) is probably fine. You can improve on it by also including acceleration (second order), but additional orders or a more accurate physics model likely to be worth the effort or cost.
- Might not be worth it - This is really the crux of the problem. Depending on your application, hardware, and other details, any one of these possible solutions could outperform another. If performance is important, you should probably try a prototype implementation of each and run benchmarks on your target devices to see what fits best. (The sad reality it that you can't easily perform benchmarks until you've already done all the work.)

Comment: I appreciate your analysis. I have thought about the problem some more and i realized that I wanted to vary the number of samples for each object depending on how fast it's moving. So heres what i'll do: I assemble my vertex buffer on the cpu which includes all of the transformations and the appropriate blend value using the alpha channel, and I'll never need to code a vertex shader.